# Implementation of a queue in Azure service bus using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am an absolute beginner with Service Bus. I want to understand the implementation of a queue using python. The documentation tells me to install Azure Python SDK. I've done that.I made the python file as per instructions, yet I am getting syntax error. I ran the file on the python shell. Did I do that right? 
 How do I know that the Azure Package is being used?

Comment: put some effort what you have done actually.

Comment: Please post your current code and the syntax error you got here.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you got a syntax error, it sounds like the issue you got was caused by a Python usage problem, not be related to Azure Service Bus SDK for Python. Without your python code, I don't know what happended in your code. Just as reference, I post some steps for using Azure Python SDK to connect Azure Service Bus.

1. Install Azure Service Bus SDK for Python via pip in a console. Open a console like CMD on Windows or terminal on Linux, type & enter `pip install azure-servicebus` if you had installed Python environment and configure it within `PATH` environment variable. If you were using a linux distribution like Ubuntu, it may be necessary to first type `sudo` at the front of the pip command.
2. Copy the servicebus namespace & the primary key for the policy name `RootManageSharedAccessKey` on Azure portal to be ready for using it in your python script.
3. Write your python script to connect Service Bus as below.

   ```
   from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService

   key_name = 'RootManageSharedAccessKey' # SharedAccessKeyName from Azure portal
   key_value = '' # SharedAccessKey from Azure portal
   sbs = ServiceBusService(service_namespace,
                       shared_access_key_name=key_name,
                       shared_access_key_value=key_value)
   ```

   Then you can use `sbs` to do other operations, such as create a queue via `sbs.create_queue('taskqueue')`, or send message via the code below.

   ```
   from azure.servicebus import Message

   msg = Message('Hello World!')
   sbs.send_queue_message('taskqueue', msg)
   ```
4. In the console, you can type `python <your script name>.py` to run it. If got any error, please update your post to let me know.

You can refer to the documents listed below to know the steps above.

1. [How to use Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues) in Python
2. [How to use Service Bus topics and subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) in Python
3. [Introduction](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicebus.html) for the usage of the service bus in Azure Python SDK
4. The usage of Python package [`azure-servicebus`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-servicebus)

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.